# Not setting the location when using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, lyx

I'm using `tikz` in `LyX`. I'm trying to build a basic graph. Is it possible to somehow add the path of the nodes without setting the location of each one?

For now I used:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.8,auto=left,node/.style={circle,draw}]
  \node[circle,draw] (A) at (0,0) {$v_1$};
  \node[circle,draw] (B) at (4,0) {$v_2$};
 \draw[->] (A)--(B) node[midway,above]{$e_0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Output:

[image]

But is it possible to remove the `at (4,0)` part so `tikz` will generator the graph alone? I don't really care where the nodes are located, I just care about the exitness of them and the paths between them. The desired code looks something like:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.8,auto=left,node/.style={circle,draw}]
  \node[circle,draw] (A) {$v_1$};
  \node[circle,draw] (B) {$v_2$};
 \draw[->] (A)--(B) node[midway,above]{$e_0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And the output should be the same (maybe `90` degree different but same logic).

The main goal is to just declare the path and `tikz` will do the hard work for me.

I was using the [WebGraphviz](http://www.webgraphviz.com/) (Graphviz in the Browser). There I could just declare the paths it would build the graph for me (without setting the locations). I understood that it is not possible to use `Graphviz` in `LyX` and everyone who uses it, uploads an image instead. I prefer to build the nodes so it would look better.

Is it possible to somehow create graph without declaring the coordinates for each node?

Comment: Yes, it seems to me you are looking for the `chains` library.

Answer (score 2):

The `graphs` library allows you not to worry about the location of nodes *(see page 408 et seq. of manual 3.1)*.

[image: graph]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[grow right=30mm,nodes={circle,draw}] {
1 ->[edge label={a}] 2   ->[edge label={b}] 3;
1 -- [bend right,edge label'={c}] 3;
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A very minimal realization of your suggestion might be

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,c/.style={circle,draw,join},every join/.style={-latex}]
\node [c,on chain] {A};
\node [c,on chain] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A slightly more sophisticated version could be

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,decorations.markings}
\newcounter{eindex}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.4cm,start chain,%
midmark/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.5 with {\stepcounter{eindex}
\node[anchor=south] at (0,0.1){$e_{\theeindex}$};}}}},
c/.style={circle,draw,join},every join/.style={-latex,midmark}]
\node [c,on chain] {A};
\node [c,on chain] {B};
\node [c,on chain] {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course the chains can go in any direction and there are many more things, as you can see in section 48 of the pgfmanual.